# Десериализация JSON в C#

Tags: c#, json

Есть класс в котором одно из свойств это объект из библиотеки dll. Суть в том, что при вызове метода JsonConvert.DeserializeObject вызывается исключение "Unable to find a default constructor to use for type xNet.CookieDictionary. Path 'cookies.remixlang', line 1, position 39."
Как мне спарсить строку в объект?
Код, который используется:

```
class Globals
{
    public static Globals info = new Globals();
    public bool isAuth = false;
    public CookieDictionary cookies = null;//из xNet.dll
}
```

Сначала сохраняю в файл:

```
File.WriteAllText(save_file, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Globals.info));
```

Пытаюсь спарсить:

```
Globals.info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Globals>(File.ReadAllText(save_file));//Исключение тут
```

Собственно что мне делать как мне быть?

Comment: Прстите если что-то не то говорю или слишком очевидное. Может быть, для CookieDictionary сделать соответствующий ему класс с теми же данными, но и с открытыми getter-ами и setter-ами (get; set;) и безпараметрическим конструктором. Исходников этого класса сходу не нашел, других идей не появилось.

Comment: А вы инициализируете вообще где либо `CookieDictionary`? Ибо у вас стоит `=null`, попробуйте сначала инициализировать, а уж затем десериализировать ваш `JSON`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо, совсем забыл, что null стоит

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понимаю, вы для работы с JSON используете библиотеку Newtonsoft.Json (JSON.NET). Для десериализации ей во многих случаях необходимо, чтобы десериализуемые типы имели конструктор без параметров. У класса `xNet.CookieDictionary` его, очевидно нету, поэтому выбрасывается данное исключение.

Если данный класс не является `sealed`-классом и имеет `public` или `protected` конструктор, вы можете его унаследовать, и создать открытый конструктор по-умолчанию без параметров:

```
class MyCookieDictionary : CookieDictionary
{
    // Здесь, возможно, потребуется передать некоторые параметры по-умолчанию
    public MyCookieDictionary() : base() { }
}

class Globals
{
    ...
    public MyCookieDictionary cookies = null;
}
```

---

Другой вариант заключается в том, чтобы для хранения сериализуемых данных использовать только простые структуры и стандартные типы, вроде `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` вместо `xNet.CookieDictionary`, с которыми JSON.NET гарантированно умеет работать, а перед сериализацией и после десериализации так или иначе преобразовать данные к необходимым типам.